# how do i create a copy or install a non-virtualenv copy of python on ubuntu?

Tags: python

I know how to create virtual environments, but I'm dealing with software that is able to detect that it is being given a virtual environment, and it refuses to run. It also won't accept the system python because that uses PEP 668 now so the software complains of being unable to install what it wants.

So I need to create a full separate copy of python on my system that is indistinguishable from the real deal, and pass its path to the software as a python interpreter.

Comment: "software that is able to detect that it is being given a virtual environment, and it refuses to run." ... Can you please elaborate on that (how you run it, how does it detect a virtual environment(*if you can tell*) and what messages/errors you get"  ... Please see if this helps https://askubuntu.com/a/1459030 ... Also if you are using Ubuntu 23.04 or other, please add the version to your question.

Comment: solved. I just downloaded the source from the python website, ran ./configure, make, and make install