# Installing python3.10 on Ubuntu23.04, alongside with python3.11 causes apt crash

Tags: apt, package-management, python, python3, 23.04

I need to use **python3.10** on **Ubuntu23.04**.

I've tried to install *python3.10* on *Ubuntu23.04*, alongside with *python3.11*.  And, it looks like it [has been installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnZns.png).

[image]

But, **python3.10-venv** [didn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m5WL.png).

[image]

Than I've tried to switch versions and try install **python3.10-venv** again, working under *python3.10*, and looks like they [have been switched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/116fT.png).

[image]

But, with *python3.10* i have [not-working package manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x21Ct.png)

[image]

*(looks like python3.11 is used in 23.04 system components)*.

I've tried to `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`, working under *python3.11* *(bc apt doesn't work with python3.10 in current situation)*, but [soon i realised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJeyt.png),

[image]

that deadsnakes [doesn't](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) support Ubuntu 23.04 for now.

So, is there any variants how to install fully working *python3.10* alongside with *python3.11* on *Ubuntu23.04*, with working package manager?

Comment: Related: [Terminal and other apps suddenly won't open](https://askubuntu.com/q/1448702)

Comment: @Raffa, thanks for response. But i have no problem with working under `python3.11` for now. In case i switch the system wide python ver to 3.11 (even without loading live disk and rerooting system, like in this linked manual), i can absolutely normally work with apt and all stuff from `ubuntu 23.04`. Main problem is to use `python3.10`. I can use this version normally, but i can't install basic packages for it, like `venv`

Comment: Prior to Python3.11, the venv package was named `python3-venv` ... You can as well do `pip3 install virtualenv` then `virtualenv env -p /bin/python3.10` ... Or even `/bin/python3.10 -m pip install virtualenv` and then `/bin/python3.10 -m virtualenv env`

Comment: @Raffa, thank you very much. Your last solution was very clear and elegant, imho. And it works pretty smooth! :) Thanks again. :)))

Comment: @Raffa, sorry about disturbing, but, all worked well, except PyCharm. It can't handle python3.10 somehow. When i'm trying to select venv in interpreter settings, it doesn't select it at all. Any thoughts? :)

Comment: Do you select the python executable in that virtual environment's directory or do you select the activation script? as the latter will not work but the former should work ... See for example how to directly use a virtual environment without activating it https://askubuntu.com/a/1459030

Comment: @Raffa, i activate venv firstly (it actually creates). It works via operating with command line. But, Pycharm builtIn methods can't run selected copy of python. I select the necessary folder and python copy via PyCharm UI, but it doesn't apply to the project in PyCharm.

Comment: Have you tried this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html ?

Comment: @Raffa, of course i did :). It doesn't work neither with manual creating nor with automatic (by pycharm, like in the link) PyCharm simply `drops` the selecting process and even doesn't show choose 3.10 interpreter in the existing interpreters list.

Comment: I don't use PyCharm myself but I'm sure there are members of this community who do and probably can help with that ... So, maybe it's time you post that in a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using python3.11 as default and [compiling python3.10 from source](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/10/compile-install-python-3-10-ubuntu/) with [adding the usr/local/bin to PATH and updating alternatives for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062608/how-to-update-alternatives-to-python-3-without-breaking-apt) (with setting python3.11 as default) solved the problem for me.